# Styled Components not loaded - React Typescript Webpack setup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Hello so I am trying styled components for the first time so I do not know where I might be going wrong because I have my **webpack** setup nicely and my **.babelrc** file.

So when I was reading through the docs of Styled component they mentioned adding this plugin `"babel-plugin-styled-components",`

**Here is my .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}
```

**So I wont be adding webpack config because when searching I never saw anything that linked styled components to webpack so I believe setup is by .babelrc**... But if **webpack** config is required please comment and I will add that.

**Here is the basic component where I wanted to use styled components**

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Styled from 'styled-components';

const Title = Styled.h1`
  color:black;
`;

export const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Brag Diary</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**The style is not made so I do now know where I might be going wrong can I please get some assistant**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to the styled component directly:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Styled from 'styled-components';

const Title = Styled.h1`
  color:black;
`;

export const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Title>Brag Diary</Title>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Quick Questions before you go let's say I want to style the div having class ```App``` I would wrap it around replace the **div** with whatever variable that I had decided? And is it best practice to isolate style to another file then import?

Comment: Yep that's how they work. It's up to you how you organise your components, but as an application grows, it can be better organised if each is in it's own individually responsible file. When you want to share high level things such as colours and font sizes, look into using [themes](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming).